# Build a .exe from batch file

Tags: batch-file, exe

**What is happening:**

So, i was just making a batch file that is clickable.

Now,i have archived what i want using a batch extension/plugin from a french website:

```
for %%b in ( 
4D534346000000005A040000000000002C000000000000000301010001000000
000000004700000001000100000800000000000000006546F2B1200062617462
6F782E65786500D7E54E4C0B040008434BB5555F685B55183F499BA06D4DB235
295311EFA4151C23E04A7C2854B2759D8EA51A92B88A14BAFCB9C9BD697A6FB8
B9B19DF32123093223F8361FF6B212F0C597227B98A26C359382B46FC38789FB
F7306E9C6011FF14D15E7FDFB9376D26854DD093FCCE39DFEFFBCE777EE7BBE7
26536F55988331D6CB7CCC34190B938116660F6F15C0F3ECE71E76E9F1F5FD97
1D91F5FD09492E09454DCD69C979219D5414551752A2A09515415684A3AFC785
793523069FE81BEEE4884E32167138D8DBAB9B890E779B791DFD0EC731E686E1
B6495F17481D8D4EC66CB9D06F37C1E2477E66ACA77BDD76A46DDAEDC341C6E6
9C8F70D8FFB805B385A48EF190DB16E4B67477B753548AFFB9497D436196B706
692B80EE0F74662083BE7ACD9FFFD50C44FC61D67453D86FB6E1A4E00A0A2A39
CFA27B6F9056E87CC54075D3F4D6AEE224CD202DF1492F913744861978D78A31
62F04FBC3F58F94678D1CC7E36C0C63E3A83286F6D14FC2BB9BB1BED1BA6691A
7B6045CD909B2F4D60E3760B74E58C63D65BF740BB1928205FFDAAB7F6097833
700AD63855CC5BEFE76E225CB8D4ACD940FAF62F506C7C81AEC745A29A2FA3CB
363D486F7CCCD931628F70D6479B863CBCB704BC49028E90AED3085E751D1BB4
DE91264D24DEBDC00B31835DDB4F52E01C02E35D6CF5DA636D468E35ACFBDDF5
1CF2FE05D35BBF8F7EE9A921EB303729E24744B4AF6F61761133E37B32BF26F3
4F7A69703452738988FBA481CE63DCA1199DA17D010EE9F92EF112C28D15F21F
A067D7EDCA50A63C655A82FFDC2AAA0A661A7B0C90270A8FE9A2A22CEDD46B69
A748ED6F1190DF67869C3C5B146BAC3BE590F6F25D2C7E067C759C1C78CCEB48
99AD8E93DFE9AD5F81D56A8C0FC13AB7B5F293EFEC3DFA21EAE1E5894E9F940E
76D5CFD73286A0328F4FDC0C14ADEBD43287BF3C81A0AA8B2E706FE3191A1A4F
D7BFF3D6E8A56FE5B7EF5FCD7A08FFB8958B569A8E59E166AF196AF08D25CB1C
29B191CC18FFF6EDFE2A7DEA0BB30D60744F985DC03883B10CAC00CBC00DA07F
2F8A877104E35C2E99CECCAB0B52F1B4124CA5788E83819D7CB7F0D334037BD8
BFC3FD002E02BBB78BDB0437E0DF5DD354FCE4442C113C1A89B01393B1D72623
A387B8C1DE884FC63A73BFBDD8BF9D242EA90BD3B2925117C8D2C1D780F3C032
B006DC060C8A87C07DB6E8478DC33B2EEA713DF36A52C91444BE9FA84FA84A49
2D8853F87F789049888BFA615DD7E45459171FF04C94B592AA45D592ACCBAA42
AB626232633B8F2BC5B27E98E20BA258DC65DD7125ABDA5A1EC2772AF101F49F
072E02CBC065E02B600DB80EDC04EE011BF639FF6D3C63454D56F42CCD6673A2
9E96F88CA6F34959496AB9126C7151D6393F9792AC5949D774B5C039B5285221
66173499178BCD6A28098DE9825AB298B45492DF11EDBFBCBF01            
) Do >>t.dat (Echo.For b=1 To len^("%%b"^) Step 2
ECHO WScript.StdOut.Write Chr^(Clng^("&H"^&Mid^("%%b",b,2^)^)^) : Next)
Cscript /b /e:vbs t.dat>batbox.ex_
Del /f /q /a t.dat >nul 2>&1
Expand -r batbox.ex_ >nul 2>&1
Del /f /q /a batbox.ex_ >nul 2>&1
```

(This build batbox.exe)

After copy and paste the batch script above to the batch file,I have a question in my head:How do i made a custom batch script that build a exe program like this?
I have readed some more stuff from some stackoverflow posts and dostip and khow that those weird 5D15... string are hex code.

**Question:**

```
For %%A in (
<hex code>
) DO >>t.dat (Echo.For b=1 To len^("%%b"^) Step 2
    ECHO WScript.StdOut.Write Chr^(Clng^("&H"^&Mid^("%%b",b,2^)^)^) : Next)
    Cscript /b /e:vbs t.dat>sample.ex_
    Del /f /q /a t.dat >nul 2>&1
    Expand -r sample.ex_ >nul 2>&1
    Del /f /q /a sample.ex_ >nul 2>&1
```

I have 2 question in my head:

1.Even though i khow how it works now,but how do i get the hex codes from exe program?

2.does this works everytime?

Anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To get the hexadecimal version of any file, open it in a hex editor.
2. Hexadecimal is an easier way of reading binary so that you only have to read a few characters instead of a bunch of zeroes and ones. The binary of a file never changes as long as the program itself, so this will always work.